# What's the difference when query using `in` and an array between two indexes?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

A collection in MongoDB with docs like below:

```
{a: 1, b: 1}
{a: 2, B: 2}
{a: 3, B: 3}
{a: 3, B: 2}
{a: 2, B: 1}
```

with uniq index `a_1_b_1` or `b_1_a_1`

Query: `{a: x, b: { $in: [....] } }`

which index better? or same?

How about query match array works?

---

Update： 
Does the shard key impact the query index？
shard key: `a_1_c_1`
extra index: `b_1_a_1`
query: `{a: x, b: y}`

1. route to the shard by `a=x` in shard key `a_1_c_1` , then query in the shard using index `b_1_a_1`
2. route by shard key and query must using shard key?

Answer (score 0):

From the MongoDB manual's section on [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/):

> > db.products.createIndex( { "item": 1, "stock": 1 } )
>
> The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important. The index will contain references to documents sorted first by the values of the item field and, within each value of the item field, sorted by values of the stock field.

Given the above, we can see that `a_1_b_1` will segment first by `a` and then by `b`, whereas `b_1_a_1` will segment first by `b` and then by `a`.

Now let's examine your query: `{a: x, b: { $in: [....] } }`
Note that this query matches a specific `a` value and a range of possible `b` values. In index `a_1_b_1` the index scan will be limited to only the matching `a` block and all `b` values will be searched for within; if, however, you use index `b_1_a_1`, then the index scan must "jump" between the different `b` blocks and search each of them for the matching `a` value.

It's typically far more efficient to access data that is "close" together, so you will want to select the index in which your matching documents are more likely to be closely located. In this case, having all of your documents in the same `a` block will likely be a much better choice as there should be less "jumping" going on, so you should go with index `a_1_b_1`.

This is grossly over-simplified, however. The actual performance impact may be negligible, particularly in cases where the range of possible `a` and `b` are quite low.

There is also an extra consideration you should make: query prefixes. If you find yourself in a situation where you sometimes perform queries with only an `a` value, then you should select index `a_1_b_1`. Likewise, if you sometimes perform queries with only a `b` value, then you should probably select `b_1_a_1`.

This is because if your query doesn't completely match an index but matches a prefix of that index, the index will still apply. Thus, in index `a_1_b_1` you can perform efficient queries on `{a: x, b: {$in: [....]}}` as well as `{a: x}`, but you cannot perform an efficient query on `{b: {$in: [....]}}`.

Finally, it's often also possible to take advantage of [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/) to have two separate indexes `a_1` and `b_1`, giving you a middle ground between performance and flexibility.

---

With everything above in mind, I wouldn't recommend concerning yourself too much with index performance until the size of your data starts to necessitate it. After all, you can drop old indexes and build new ones as needed. Use what works for now, monitor the performance over time, and reassess when it looks like you might be outgrowing what you're currently using.

Comment: thanks for the explain, there are billions docs in the collection, `a` and `b` both has large range. One more question is: if the collection is sharded by index `b_1_a_1`, will the query `{a:x, b: {$in: [..]}}` performed as a multi of `{b: x, a: y}` ?

Comment: @nFeng Unfortunately I don't have any experience in sharded collections and only have a cursory knowledge of how they work, so I don't have an answer for that.